# If someone has a hashed password, how long till they decrypt it?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking

Earlier my friend suggested that we have a race to see who could decrypt a hashed password first. I want to do it but I don't want it to be an all month thing. I know when passwords are hashed they can't be unhashed but if someone were to have the hash (no salt) of a password with the parameters being 6 char long and only contain lower case letters along with numbers, how long would it take for them to generate a wordlist and hash each one to see if they match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too long.

If I understand you question correctly, you'll be using passwords that are 6 characters long, with only lowercase letters and numbers. So each character can only take be one of 36 possible outcomes (26 letters + 10 digits)

Effectively it's `36^6` combination which is 2.1 Billion.

Obviously it depends on the hash in question, and the hardware you're using, see [here](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) has a good comparison.

For e.g if you're using MD5, this would be cracked in under a second. Even with SHA-3 this wouldn't take more than hour. If you go wild with multiple high-end GPUs, this would be a walk in the park -- even if the password were truly random.

And I'm assuming you're brute-forcing every possible combination -- not from a wordlist. Most programs, like hashcat will allow you to bruteforce without a wordlist. Which seems apt for your use-case.